# How to create custom toast message for different item in a list in a custom adapter

Tags: android

So I have a program where I need to display a different toast depending on what item the user selects in a list. I created a custom adapter since I need to add pictures to the list and created an object that goes by the name Day that contains the day of the week, the image, and the custom text that needs to go in the toast. My problem is that I don't know how to create an onItemClickListener that will use my custom text for my toast.
This is my custom adapter

```
public class DayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Day> {
```

private Context mContext;
int mResource;

```
public DayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Day> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    String jour = getItem(position).getDay();
    int image = getItem(position).getImage();
    String message = getItem(position).getMessage();

    Day journee = new Day(jour, image, message);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

    TextView tvJour = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewJour);
    ImageView tvImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewJour);


    tvJour.setText(jour);
    tvImage.setImageResource(image);


    return convertView;
}
```

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView liste;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    liste = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dayList);
    ArrayList<Day> semaine = new ArrayList<Day>();
    Day lundi = new Day("Lundi", R.drawable.happyface, "Prog lundi");
    Day mardi = new Day("Mardi", R.drawable.happyface, "Musique mardi");
    Day mercredi = new Day("Mercredi", R.drawable.happyface, "Mercredi");
    Day jeudi = new Day("Jeudi", R.drawable.beer, "Work jeudi");
    Day vendredi = new Day("Vendredi", R.drawable.beer, "also work vendredi");
    Day samedi = new Day("Samedi", R.drawable.malade, "also also work samedi");
    Day dimanche = new Day("Dimanche", R.drawable.etude, "Love Dimanche");

    semaine.add(lundi);
    semaine.add(mardi);
    semaine.add(mercredi);
    semaine.add(jeudi);
    semaine.add(vendredi);
    semaine.add(samedi);
    semaine.add(dimanche);

    DayAdapter adapter = new DayAdapter (this, R.layout.row, semaine);

    liste.setAdapter(adapter);

    liste.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String messa  = adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, messa, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: In your `ArrayAdapter` class set the `onItemClickListener` on the item that you want to be clicked. Then inside, you can create a Toast.

Comment: What item in your listView needs to be clicked for the Toast?

Comment: I need to click the whole item(I want the toast to pop up when I click on the item of the list)

Comment: Is your app crashin or what?

Comment: My app is not crashing, all I am getting when I click the Item is a directory, it doesn't display my custom toast

Comment: Do this in your ArrayAdapter: `convertview.setOnClickListener()`

Comment: Make your toast in the listener. This should be in the ArrayAdapter, not MainActivity

Comment: Could you elaborate on convertView.setOnClickListener(), what am i supposed to put in the ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the Toast in your ArrayAdapter class, specifically in the `getView` method like

```
convertview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         Toast.makeText(mContext, "Custom Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }

});
```

If you want, you can use an `onTouchListener` instead of the `onClickListener`.

Comment: You are most welcome Alex. I am happy that I was able to help!